# How to convert local time to GMT in SSRS report

Tags: datetime, reporting-services

In SSRS report I have one TextBox which display local time to GMT. Currently, I am just adding 4 hours to the local time as I know server is in ET zone:

`=Format(DateAdd(DateInterval.Hour,4,Now()),"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm") & " GMT"`

But if server moves to some other time zone this won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SSRS, you have access to the .NET object model

```
=String.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm} GMT", DateTime.UtcNow)
```